# Rails form not saving 'Type:' field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a simple `Post` scaffold which has `title:string body:text category:string`. I later added `type:string` (and performed the migration) to the model and added the selection fields in new.html.erb and edit.html.erb. I also added validation for all these fields.

```
<%= f.label :type %>
<%= f.select :type, Post::TYPES, :prompt => "Select post type" %>
```

When I try and create a post it gives me:

"There were problems with the following fields:
Type can't be blank
Type is not included in the list"

Even though I DO make a selection. Am I missing something obvious here?

Select code from Post class:

```
TYPES = [
  ["Job", "job"],
  ["Volunteer", "vol"]
]

validates_presence_of :title, :body, :category, :type
validates_inclusion_of :category, :in => CATEGORIES.map {|disp, value| value}
validates_inclusion_of :type, :in => TYPES.map {|disp, value| value}
```

Comment: You asked if you were missing something obvious so… did you restart the server after performing the migration? :)

Comment: I sure did. This was happening yesterday so the system has been rebooted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` field is a reserved field used for single table inheritance(STI). You have to rename the field.

Refer to [this](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords) article for more details

Edit: Changed the link to point to the article provide by Matchu.

Comment: List of all reserved Rails words: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, you can use field called **type** in Rails 4 by setting **inheritance_column** to something else:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :ruby_type
end
```

In Rails 3 and below, use method **set_inheritance_column** instead.