# Associations of records of one table are in another

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

### I have:

Two database tables:

```
 Users: id, title
 Infos: id, type, user_id_createdby, user_id_addressedto, text
```

---

in Infos I have records of setting a dates of meetings between users:

```
Infos record: id: 1, type: "nextmeeting", user_id_createdby: 47, user_id_addressedto: 51,  text: "2011/01/13"
```

*beside "nextmeeting" I have other types of data between users as well*

---

while a User logged in I'm showing him a list of users with whom he has a meetings by collecting: unique `user_id_addressedto` **and** `current_user => user_id_createdby` 
from Info to array `@repilents` and then `User.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @repilents})`

---

### Question:

How I can sort list of Users by dates from Infos.text where type: "nextmeeting"?

like:

- User 4 - 2011/01/05
- User 8 - 2011/01/13
- User 2 - 2011/01/21
- User 5 - Next meeting not defined
- User 3 - Next meeting not defined

Comment: refactored title. is it ok now?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that there will only be one row in Infos that has the type "nextmeeting", you can use a left outer join to link users to meetings:

```
@users = User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN infos ON infos.user_id_createdby = users.id")
```

To order by the descending date:

```
@users = User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN infos ON infos.user_id_createdby = users.id").order("infos.text DESC")
```

Now some random comments:

- type is a reserved word and you shouldn't use it as a column name (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293618/rails-form-not-saving-type-field-newbie)
- storing dates as text is going to make your life difficult
- You might want to rethink this generic "infos" column and make a distinct Meeting model.

Comment: Thank you Spike! 1) There will be not one meeting, but several and one of the goals in future to map a timeline of meetings for each user from list. 2) actually column name not type but tip, I also faced with this reserved word, just used it in example for better expression. 3) I'm storing date in text because in this table other users interactions are stored, like comments.

Comment: Hi Spike, I've used: `@users = User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN infoshkas ON infoshkas.user_id_createdby = #{current_user.id} WHERE infoshkas.tip = 'nvz' AND user_id_addressedto = users.id")` and it correctly rised required record, that I'm very thankful to you. but in `<%= debug @users %>` still there is no pair `user.nvz` that was expected to come from Infoshkas, only pairs from user. Kindly asking you to help me with this issue